# git: need to parse commit messages looking for pattern and storing in list

Tags: git, grep, commit-message

all of my git commit messages start with

```
  refs #SOME_NUMBER
```

where SOME_NUMBER is a number from 1 up. I would like to parse all commmit messages on 
my working branch, store all of the SOME_NUMBERs in a list, remove duplicates, and save to file. Not really sure where to start....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that pretty easily with this shell one-liner:

```
$ git log --format=%s | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | sed 's/#\(.*\)/\1/' | sort -n | uniq > refs.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `git log --format=%s` displays the first line of every commit message
2. `cut -f 2 -d ' '` splits the line by a space, and prints the second part of the (the `#SOME_NUMBER` portion)
3. `sed 's/#\(.*\)/\1/'` removes the number sign from the number
4. `sort` sorts the entries in ascending numerical order
5. `uniq` ensures that each number is only printed once
6. `> refs.txt` prints the output to a file called `refs.txt`.

Comment: To sort numbers, use "sort -n". Also uniq is not reliable unless sorted first; it only removes consecutive duplicates, so it is not just a "nice touch", but required.